# How to change drive letter from command prompt or powershell in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, disk, drive

I wants to change my computer disk D:\ to E:\ from command prompt or powershell. Is there any way other than 'diskpart'?

Comment: what speaks against diskpart ? This would have been my suggestion.

Comment: By "Computer Disk", do you mean System Disk (i.e. the Disk the OS is on, the Boot Disk)?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming when you said "computer disk" you do *not* mean the System/Boot Disk, here is a solution using PowerShell. Note the variables. You can either replace them with the actual Drive Letters, or set them ahead of time.

```
Get-Partition -DriveLetter $old | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter $new
```

Note here that `$old` and `$new` does **not** include the `:` character. So in your particular case (changing from D to E), you can use the following.

```
Get-Partition -DriveLetter D | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter E
```

Note also that you will need Admin Rights. So run PowerShell as Admin.

Comment: This also requires Server 2012 / Windows 8 and above.

Comment: Also doesnt work on the DVD / CD drive as there is no 'partition'

Comment: Get-Partition -PartitionNumber 1 | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter X

Comment: @Timo You can do it with `New-SmbMapping` (to add a new one) and `Remove-SmbMapping` (to remove an old one). See [0] and [1].

[0]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbmapping?view=win10-ps
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/remove-smbmapping?view=win10-ps